# dividing selected column with 100 in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, math

i have a data frame df1 as
[image: dataframe]

I wanted to divide col2,col3 by 90

please suggest the solution

Comment: You might want to look into `df.apply`. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply

Comment: @HarryStuart `df.apply` will be slower. Also, it's not required in this case. A simple `df.div` would solve OP's question.

Comment: I only suggested it in a comment since I think it's an important method (and applicable to this case albeit slightly less optimal) to be ware of. It allows for greater generality also, if, for example, there are entries that cannot be converted to an int etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df1[['col2', 'col3']] = df1[['col2', 'col3']] / 90
```

OR use [`df.div`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.div.html):

```
df1[['col2', 'col3']] = df1[['col2', 'col3']].div(90)
```

If the columns types are not `int` or `float`, you can do this:

```
df1[['col2', 'col3']] = df1[['col2', 'col3']].astype(int).div(90)
```